# SUM number in database using HTML while name exists, if not add new column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have got a problem.

Here is my script

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("mysql.cba.pl","piotr_luszcz","password","leggendinho");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM moneytable WHERE name LIKE '$_POST[post_name]'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { 
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO moneytable (name, money) VALUES ('$_POST[post_name]', '$_POST[post_money]')");
 }  else  {  
     $sql = "UPDATE moneytable SET  money = money + '$_POST[post_money]'" ;
 }
```

Here is my problem:

I need to do a html page where im putting name and money that person needs to give me back. Adding person name and money is ok into mysql, but I can't upgrade column money if name in database exists, its just making a new column.

I don't know if I've written "column" correctly, I mean the data you put into database

Comment: I hope that's not your real login for the database server. If it is, you need to change it asap... You have several problems apart from that: Sql injection, mixing mysql and mysqli and you don't have a `WHERE` condition on the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE query should have WHERE condition, otherwise it will affect all the rows in your table.Change your UPDATE query like below:

$sql = "UPDATE moneytable SET  money = money + '".$_POST[post_money]."' WHERE name ='".$_POST['name']."'" ;